# dotnet core 3.1 web api - The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am creating a Web API using dotnet core 3.1 and having trouble simply getting a configuration setting. Here is the error:

```
The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context
```

The startup.cs references the configuration:

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
```

I have looked at a number of examples and they all seem to utilize the

```
var connectionString =  Configuration["ConnectionString"];
```

I see the value in the appsettings.json and like the fact there is a appsettings.Development.json file for configurations as well. Just having trouble accessing them.

I am sure this is something simple, but it's taking me a long time to track down for some reason. It would be great if the WeatherForecast template had a reference to a configuration value in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")
```

Make sure you have `ConnectionStrings` sections, there is example:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Default": "Server=DESKTOP-L4QDV84;Database=Tournaments_MSA;Trusted_Connection=True;",
  "HangfireConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-L4QDV84;Database=HangfireDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"
}
```

**EDIT:**

`IConfiguration` instance already exists in service collection, so you can easelly access it by adding parameter in your controller constructor.

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}
```

And then you can use it in your controller's methods

Comment: But in vscode in the Controller class the "Configuration" is underlined, and giving me the error. I can't reference Configuration in the controller.

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you. As a bonus question, if I add a section in appsettings.json which is not under "ConnectionStrings", how do I get information from it? I can't use Configuration.GetConnectionString("xxxx"), so what do I call?

Comment: I got it. Found https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#getvalue and see that we can call it like Configuration["section:key"]